# Can't figure out what syntax error is when trying to convert Int to Categorical

Tags: pandas, syntax, integer, categorical-data

I have a variable (Bad Indicator) which is also my target. It is currently INT 64 and I am trying to convert to categorical but am getting a syntax error but I can't figure out why.Converting DTI from Object to Float worked. . .

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
project = pd.read_csv('c:/users/Brandon Thomas/Project.csv')

project.dtypes
90+ Perf                                       int64
Bankruptcy Code                              float64
Bad Indicator                                  int64
RR Downgrade                                  object
Beacon Range                                  object
Product Grouping                              object
Final Product Grouping                        object
dtype: object

project["DTI"] = pd.to_numeric(project.DTI, errors='coerce')
project['Bad Indicator']=pd.categorical(project.Bad Indicator)

File "<ipython-input-166-b6f5f0432024>", line 2
    project['Bad Indicator']=pd.categorical(project.Bad Indicator)
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You cannot use `.` to reference a column name with spaces. Reference it as you do on the LHS of the assignment: `project['Bad Indicator']`

Comment: `project.Bad Indicator` is not valid becaue there's a space. Use `project['Bad Indicator']`